# C linked list define how to reimplement a list

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault, definition

Hi this is probably a stupid question to ask with a simple solution but I just can't find an answer in the internet.

So I was exercising for an exam and worked on an assignment. The program has the job to find out what the value in the center of a linked list is (if the length of the list is an odd number)

The structdef is:

```
typedef struct IntList IntList;
struct IntList {
    int value;
    IntList* next;
};
```

and my exact problem right now is that I get a segmentation fault when I try using:

```
list = list->next;
```

I want to go step by step in a loop to go to the wished list at the nth position (the center) of the linked list.

Someone knows how I have to rewrite this? If you need more Information to help just say so and I will explain more.

With that function I check the length of the list and in my other function I have a loop which only goes to the mid of the length.

```
int length_list(IntList* list) {
    int n = 0;
    for(IntList* node = list; node != NULL; node = node->next) n++;
    return n;
}
```

Comment: A minimal working example would be helpful. But, given the lines in your question, `list` is probably `NULL` at some point...

Comment: Actually I putted it in a loop which makes sure that it wont get to the end of the list i can show you

Comment: I actually deleted and rewrote my function... I dont know why but now it works eventhough I didn't change anything at all... Thank you caylee for your help

Comment: @SerdarK. "I dont know why but now it works eventhough I didn't change anything at all" This is mother of all red flags especially if you are working with pointers. I suggest you to investigate further, since it usually means you got unlucky before or lucky now. Either way the problem still persists and there is something wrong in your code.

Comment: The `length_list` function is correct. However it will fail if the list hasn't been created corrctly, most of the time it's the `next`  pointer of the last element that is not NULL but points somewhere where it shouldn't. The problem is somewhere in code you didn't show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After this loop ends `for(IntList* node = list; node != NULL; node = node->next) n++;` you surely have `node==NULL`.
That is not immediatly a problem.
But depending on what you do with the value of `n` which you return you might have an off-by-one problem. E.g. in a list with exactly one entry (1 is odd after all), the attempt to use a value which is 1 too high could result in an attempt to access a non-existing node.

Because of this I suspect that your problem might be solved by changing the loop to
`for(IntList* node = list; node->next != NULL; node = node->next) n++;`, so that it ends on the last existing node, instead of behind. The return value will be lower, whatever you do with it will be "more-careful".

That or try something similar with the small code fragment you show and ask about, `list = list->next;` only do that if the `next` is not NULL, not if only `list` is not NULL.